# get the rank of the person in descending order in mysql with where clause

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have tried the http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/df2ec/1 to get the data:I am trying to get the rank of name A which is 4 but I am unable to do it.

```
SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank, name, vote 
FROM uservotes, (SELECT @rownum := 0) t ORDER BY vote DESC
```

in data table:

```
create table uservotes(id int, name varchar(50), vote int);

INSERT INTO uservotes VALUES
(1, 'A', 34),
(2, 'B', 80),
(3, 'bA', 30),
(4, 'C', 8),
(5, 'D', 4),
(6, 'E', 14),
(7, 'F', 304),
(8, 'AA', 42),
(9, 'Ab', 6),
(10, 'Aa', 10);
```

I am unable to get the where clause .Basically I want to know which rank is the name based on the votes .I tried :

```
SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank, name, vote 
FROM uservotes WHERE name= A , (SELECT @rownum := 0) t ORDER BY vote DESC
```

But I am getting an error.I really appreciate any help.Thanks in Advance.

Error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' (SELECT @rownum := 0) t ORDER BY vote DESC' at line 2: SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank, name, vote FROM uservotes WHERE name= A , (SELECT @rownum := 0) t ORDER BY vote DESC

Comment: what's the error? also what is A in the where clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Try this one:

```
SELECT 
    @i:=@i+1 AS rn, 
    t.*
FROM 
    uservotes AS t,
    (SELECT @i:=0) AS tbl
    ORDER BY vote desc
```

2) Then getting the particular row for A is easy:

```
select * From
(
SELECT 
    @i:=@i+1 AS rn, 
    t.*
FROM 
    uservotes AS t,
    (SELECT @i:=0) AS tbl
ORDER BY vote desc

) x where x.name = 'A'
```

Comment: SELECT 
    @i:=@i+1 AS rn, 
    t.*
FROM 
    uservotes AS t,
    (SELECT @i:=0) AS tbl where name="A"
ORDER BY vote desc  ::::: **I tried the above code and this still gives me rank 1 not 4**

Comment: @jason No, my code gives 4 for rn. Maybe you're looking wrongly at the ID not at the rn. See here. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/208045/5 The insert statements in your SQL Fiddle seem weird. Replay it all slowly :)

Comment: Awesome it worked can you please explain it briefly what is  t.* and x.name.I really appreciate it.

Comment: @jason Sure. So x is the whole result set returned from my query 1). As you can see 1) is nested into 2). And t is just an alias in 1) for your main table - uservotes. And @i is doing the rownum simulation.

Comment: @jason See Peter Johnson's answer (answered Aug 12 '10 at 17:26) here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895110/row-number-in-mysql Basically I just adapted it for your case.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank, name, vote 
FROM uservotes, (SELECT @rownum := 0) t where name='A' ORDER BY vote DESC
```

To get the rank:

```
select rank, name, vote
from (SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank, name, vote 
FROM uservotes, (SELECT @rownum := 0) t ORDER BY vote DESC) z
where name='A';
```

Comment: no thats not right because the rank becomes 1 which is not true.That was the problem I am facing.

Comment: So what are your expected results then, you didn't mention anything to that affect in your question. @jason The missing quotes around `A` would throw an error.

Comment: I'm pointing out that your where clause is in the wrong place. It should be after the subquery table t. I have no idea what you're trying to do

Comment: Your SQLFiddle doesn't have a `rank 14` the only `14` in your fiddle is `(6, 'E', 14),` and it's the letter `E` not `A`. So like `D. Rattansingh` said, we have no idea what you're trying to do. @jason

Comment: I am trying to get the rank of name A which is 4 but I am unable to do it.I updated that in my question just now sorry.

Comment: How is this rank being determined?

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.name, (select count(*) + 1 from uservotes b where (a.vote > b.vote)) as rank 
from uservotes a having name="A" order by rank
```